# Slicing a Numpy array based on characters of string elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having some problems with Numpy array slicing based on a boolean mask.

I can do the following masking successfully, where I select integers that are less than 10.

```py
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 4]
arr = np.array(L1)
mask = arr[:] < 10
print(mask) # [ True  True  True False False  True]
print(arr[mask]) # [1 2 3 4] <-- CORRECT
```

The same strategy also works for slicing an array of strings to match a specific string:

```py
L2 = ['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac']
arr = np.array(L2)
mask = arr[:] == 'foo'
print(mask) # [False False  True False False False]
print(arr[mask]) # ['foo'] <-- CORRECT
```

However, the slicing strategy does not work when checking a character of each string in the array. Here, I want to select strings in the array that start with the character 'a'.

```py
L2 = ['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac']
arr = np.array(L2)
mask = arr[:][0] == 'a'
print(mask) # False
print(arr[mask]) # [] <-- WRONG
```

How can I create that mask correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [192]: alist = ['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac']
In [193]: arr = np.array(alist)
```

The straightforward list comprehension:

```
In [194]: [a[0]=='a' for a in alist]
Out[194]: [True, False, False, True, False, True]
```

It also works with the array, but slower (iteration on arrays is slower than on lists):

```
In [195]: timeit [a[0]=='a' for a in alist]
707 ns ± 5.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [196]: timeit [a[0]=='a' for a in arr]
4.88 µs ± 9.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

String `startswith` is also an option:

```
In [197]: [a.startswith('a') for a in alist]
Out[197]: [True, False, False, True, False, True]
In [198]: timeit [a.startswith('a') for a in alist]
1.14 µs ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`numpy` doesn't have its own string processing tools.  It has `np.char` functions, but they just apply python string methods, without speed improvement:

```
In [200]: np.char.startswith(arr, 'a')
Out[200]: array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
In [201]: timeit np.char.startswith(arr, 'a')
12.5 µs ± 297 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You get the best speed if you start and end with a list.  Iterating on array, or converting the boolean list back to array takes time.

Rereading your code I see you want to select the items, not just create the mask.  Then the list comprehension should be:

```
In [215]: [a for a in alist if a[0]=='a']
Out[215]: ['abc', 'az', 'ac']
In [216]: timeit [a for a in alist if a[0]=='a']
645 ns ± 3.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

====

As for your failed code

`[:]` does nothing for you, in any of the expressions:

```
In [213]: arr[:]
Out[213]: array(['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac'], dtype='<U3')
```

So you are just checking that the first element of `arr` is 'a'`.  You aren't testing the first string of each element.

```
In [214]: arr[0]=='a'
Out[214]: False
```

Comment: I think building a mask with a list comprehension is the most generalizable approach. Using a specialized function like `np.char.startswith()` would be difficult to remember.

Comment: Thanks for also explaining why `arr[:][0] == 'a'` didn't work in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.char.startswith`:

```
arr[np.char.startswith(arr, "a")]
```

Output:

```
array(['abc', 'az', 'ac'], dtype='<U3')
```

Note that this, by default, uses the first index (i.e. `0`). Use can use `start` parameter to act as indexing:

```
arr[np.char.startswith(arr, "a", 1)]
```

Output:

```
array(['bac', 'bar'], dtype='<U3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple [`List Comprehension`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
In [3403]: L2 = ['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac']

In [3404]: arr = np.array(L2)  

In [3411]: res = np.array([i for i in arr if i.startswith('a')])

In [3412]: res
Out[3412]: array(['abc', 'az', 'ac'], dtype='<U3')
```

**OR, if you want to use `mask`:**

Use [`np.char.startswith`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.startswith.html)

```
In [3415]: mask = np.char.startswith(arr, 'a')
In [3417]: print(arr[mask])
['abc' 'az' 'ac']
```

Comment: Thanks. The list comprehension approach is the more intuitive one.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in numpy 1.23.0, you will be able to slice strings in an array. The following will work, without making any copies:

```
L2 = np.array(['abc', 'bac', 'foo', 'az', 'bar', 'ac'])
mask = L2[:, None].view('U1')[:, 0] == 'a'
print(mask)      # True, False, False, True, False, True
print(arr[mask]) # 'abc', 'az', 'ac'
```

I'm writing an even simpler method, built on this change ([here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694)) that will allow the following:

```
mask = np.char.slice_(L2, stop=1) == 'a'
```

Again, fully vectorized and without copying.